# how can I set my objects in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have lots of details. I want to stack them within an array, can I do that?

```
detailObj = {

    textDetail: "hello this is my text!",
    id: "tooltip_businessDetails"

};

var idArray[0] = detailObg;
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Your above code has a typo in the last line. probably should be `var idArray[0] = detailObj;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes:

```
var idArray = [
    {
        textDetail: "hello this is my text!",
        id: "tooltip_businessDetails"
    },
    {
        textDetail: "another",
        id: "anotherid"
    },
    // ...and so on
];
```

Or if you already have variables pointing at them:

```
var idArray = [detailObj, anotherDetailObj, yetAnotherDetailObj];
```

You can also do it dynamically after array creation:

```
var idArray = [];
idArray.push(detailObj);
idArray.push({
    textDetail: "another",
    id: "anotherid"
});
idArray.push(yetAnotheretailObj);
```

And you can do it the way you tried to, just with a slight change:

```
var idArray = [];
idArray[0] = detailObj;
idArray[1] = anotherDetailObj;
```

Any time you set an array element, the array's `length` property is updated to be one greater than the element you set if it isn't already (so if you set `idArray[2]`, `length` becomes `3`).

Note that JavaScript arrays are *sparse*, so you can assign to `idArray[52]` without creating entries for `0` through `51`. In fact, JavaScript arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html).

Comment: @thormayer: Good deal, glad that helped. I just expanded it slightly, having seen your edit to the question. Best,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Damn! How can you write that fast!

Comment: @VisioN: LOL -- Possibly the best advice my mother gave me when I was in high school was to take typing. She said "You're into computers, so you may as well know how to touch-type." I took her advaice, and there we are, it's been serving me well for over 25 years... :-)

Answer (score 3):

instead of doing this thing use  below code

```
var arr = [];

arr.push(detailobj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use object-oriented approach:

```
var detail = function(id, text) {
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
};

​var arr = [];
arr.push(new detail("myid", "mytext"));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to stack them within an array, can I do that ?

Yes you can do that. Array in JavaScript are flexible and can hold objects as well.

**Example:**

```
var myArr = [];
myArr.push(detailObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
var idArray = [detailObj1, detailObj2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one :

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray.push(<your object>)
```

Comment: while it is good to know that the `new Array` constructor exists, i would never recommend using it over `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
detailObj = {

    textDetail: "hello this is my text!",
    id: "tooltip_businessDetails"

};

var array = [];
for(var key in detailObj) {
   array.push(detailObj[key]);
}
alert(array[0]);
```